# How to write sql statement

Tags: mysql

Im stuck of how to write mySQL to retrieve different status of different product between two tables after combine all the data of  name and lot no.

```
SELECT c.name, c.lot_no, t1 AS Product 1, t2 AS Product 2
FROM (SELECT name, lot_no FROM table_product1 
UNION SELECT name, lot_no FROM table_product2 ) c
RIGHT JOIN                                                                                 table_product1.status t1 ON ((c.name = name) AND (c.lot_no = lot_no))
RIGHT JOIN
table_product2.status t2 ON ((c.name = name) AND (c.lot_no = lot_no))
```

table_product1 : name, lot_no, status

table_product2 : name, lot_no, status --> table c : name, lot_no, status product 1, status product 2

Answer (score 0):

By doing a Right Join on BOTH status tables, you're excluding any product that is not on BOTH of the status tables.  You might try this:

```
SELECT
   c.name
   ,c.lot_no
   ,t1.status AS "Product 1"
   ,t2.status AS "Product 2"
FROM (
   SELECT name, lot_no FROM table_product1 
   UNION
   SELECT name, lot_no FROM table_product2
) c
JOIN table_product1 t1 ON ((c.name = name) AND (c.lot_no = lot_no))
JOIN table_product2 t2 ON ((c.name = name) AND (c.lot_no = lot_no))
```

This should give you a null in either or both columns if you don't have a status for that product.  If you want to eliminate the nulls in both columns, you can add this:

```
WHERE t1.status is not null and t2.status is not null
```

(I'm presuming there is a column in t1 and t2 called "status".  If the column name is different, you'll need to change that.)

Comment: yup. The column name is different. Thats why im running crazy on this code. i have no idea to solve it

Comment: Did my answer help?  Did you figure it out?  Do you need more help still?  (Sorry, lost track of this thread for a while.)